# java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information

Tags: java-8, soap, proxy

Estoy tratando llamar desde mi aplicación Java a un Webservice de Soap de la siguiente manera:

```
public String getLoginServiciosGeneral() throws Exception {
        String idSesion = "";
        try{
            ProxySelector.setDefault(new MyProxySelector());
            //LoginServiciosGeneralService service = new LoginServiciosGeneralService(new URL("https://XXXXXX.es/services/ws/LoginServiciosGeneral?wsdl"));
            LoginServiciosGeneralService service = new LoginServiciosGeneralService();
            LoginServiciosGeneralPortType port = service.getLoginServiciosGeneral();
            
            System.out.println("vamos a ver si hemos llegado hasta aqui");
            
            System.setProperty("sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout", "30000");
            System.setProperty("sun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout", "30000");
            
            String xmlRespuesta = port.loginServiciosGeneral(construirCData());
            
            idSesion = recupearIdSesionFromXML(xmlRespuesta);
            System.out.println("hasta aca");
            
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception. Problemas en la llamada al servicio loginServiciosGeneral, motivo: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    
        return idSesion;
    }
```

Donde MyProxySelector es

```
public class MyProxySelector extends ProxySelector {

    @Override
    public List<Proxy> select(URI uri) {
        // TODO Apéndice de método generado automáticamente
        System.out.println("Conectarse a " + uri.toString());
        //Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("XXXX.es", 443));
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("http://proxy.XXXX.es", 8080));
        ArrayList<Proxy> listProxy = new ArrayList<Proxy>();
        listProxy.add(proxy);
        return listProxy;
    }

    @Override
    public void connectFailed(URI uri, SocketAddress sa, IOException ioe) {
        // TODO Apéndice de método generado automáticamente
        System.err.println("Fallo en conectarse a " + uri.toString());
        System.err.println("Motivo: " + ioe.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Al ejecutar falla en la linea **String xmlRespuesta = port.loginServiciosGeneral(construirCData()** se produce el siguiente error:

> [27/03/24 10:08:34:170 CET] 000000c8 SystemErr     R
> javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: java.net.ConnectException:
> Connection timed out: no further information [27/03/24 10:08:34:172
> CET] 000000c8 SystemErr     R     at
> org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.createSystemException(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1363)
> [27/03/24 10:08:34:174 CET] 000000c8 SystemErr     R  at
> org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.demarshalFaultResponse(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1089)
> [27/03/24 10:08:34:175 CET] 000000c8 SystemErr     R  at
> org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitBareMethodMarshaller.demarshalFaultResponse(DocLitBareMethodMarshaller.java:417)
> [27/03/24 10:08:34:175 CET] 000000c8 SystemErr     R  at
> org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.getFaultResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:632)
> [27/03/24 10:08:34:175 CET] 000000c8 SystemErr     R  at
> org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.createResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:566)
> [27/03/24 10:08:34:176 CET] 000000c8 SystemErr     R  at
> org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:432)
> [27/03/24 10:08:34:176 CET] 000000c8 SystemErr     R  at
> org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:213)
> [27/03/24 10:08:34:176 CET] 000000c8 SystemErr     R  at
> com.sun.proxy.$Proxy103.loginServiciosGeneral(Unknown Source)

Estos son los datos para acceder a los servicios de SOAP:

> Proxy     href: "http://proxy.XXXX.es:8080/" Request Headers
> Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8   User-Agent:
> PostmanRuntime/7.34.0     Accept: */*     Cache-Control: no-cache
> Postman-Token: f01d4340-b382-457f-9369-a34c45c9968d     Host: XXXX.es
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br  Connection: keep-alive
> Content-Length: 12983

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Muchas gracias